# Difference between custom and seeded tables in oracle apps

Tags: plsqldeveloper, oracle-ebs, oracle-apps, oracle-sql-data-modeler

While working with oracle HRMS module I have came across many tabels like fnd_user, per_all_people_f etc...but I could not understand what are custom and seeded tables in oracle.
Can you please tell me the difference between seeded and custom tables in oracle apps alongwith examples?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Seeded tables are tables that contains initial data provided by the system. As an example the users table should contain at least an administrator for Oracle HRMS to be usable.

All the tables found in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/21d/oedma/index.html) would be seeded tables.

User-defined tables would be the opposite, any table that wasn't initially defined by the system but by users with enough privileges.

Comment: Custom table is same as user defined tables?